# Edit a Single Event in an Event Series in Apex

Tags: apex, event, recurring

I need to edit a custom field on an Activity for a single Event in a series.  Whenever I make the change and update it in Apex, it changes the value for all of the events in the series.

In the Lightning UI, you can make a change and specify that it is for the single event only.  It changes the `IsRecurrence2Exclusion` value to true to indicate that it should be separate from the rest of the series, but that field is read only so it can't be changed through Apex.

Is it possible to update a single event in a series through Apex? Is there a set of conditions to change the `IsRecurrence2Exclusion` field to true?

For example, if there are two events in a series:

```
List<Event> events = [SELECT Id, Subject, Custom_Field__c FROM Event]
// will have the following:
// events[0]: event1Id, Event Subject, Custom Field Value
// events[1]: event2Id, Event Subject, Custom Field Value

Event eventToUpdate = new Event(Id = event1Id, Custom_Field__c = 'new value');
update eventToUpdate

events = [SELECT Id, Subject, Custom_Field__c FROM Event]
// will have the following where both custom fields are updated instead of just the first one
// events[0]: event1Id, Event Subject, new value
// events[1]: event2Id, Event Subject, new value
```

Comment: You should use [edit] and show the MVR of your apex code

Comment: I added some code, but not sure it helps much

Comment: Idea: try Updating all of `events` with events[0] having the changed `Custom_Field__c` value and events[1], [2], ... using their existing `Custom_Field__c` values

Comment: That doesn't work, they both still get overwritten with the second value

Comment: short of putting a trigger on Event with debugging every event field and then running the change in the lightning UI to see what happens under the covers, I'm out of ideas